# Отсортировать словарь по двум критериям

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть словарь: `{4: 4, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 5: 4, 6: 3}`
Его нужно отсортировать по двум критериям: сортируем значения по убыванию, если значения равны, то сортируем по возрастанию ключей. При этом вывести нужно максимум 3 значения, дальше не нужно. В общем, я задействовал встроенную сортировку, но происходит time limit. Код:

```
for i in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))[:3]:
    print(i[0], end=' ')
print(' ')
```

Как ускорить? Каждый раз tuple создавать неэффективно, но я не знаю, как можно по-другому отсортировать, если писать свою сортировку, то все равно медленнее

Comment: В словаре ключи не могут быть равны. Так что попробуйте просто отсортировать ключи по убыванию, а потом вывести первые три элемента.

Comment: @EzikBro это условно ключи/значения. А по факту первый столбец и второй столбец. Второй сортируем по убыванию, если есть равные значения - сортируем первый по возрастанию. Сейчас исправлю вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте heapq.nsmallest, оно должно быть быстрее, если нужно только несколько элементов из сортировки

Comment: heapq.nsmallest(3, dictionary.items(), key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))